# Compare two arrays and find each values count using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays.

Here is my array.

```
 var arr=[
"08-01-2017",
"07-31-2017",
"07-30-2017",
"07-29-2017",
"07-28-2017",
"07-27-2017",
"07-26-2017"]
```

Here is another array

```
 var arr1= [
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "Home",
        "REFERER": "",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-31T05:44:06.743Z",
        "S_ID": "80067826-0cad-4806-b40e-8e5d8be18e53",
        "C_ID": "",
        "C_NAME": "",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c20a636c81d38dc77c626"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "ProductlistPage",
        "REFERER": "Home",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-30T05:44:22.425Z",
        "S_ID": "7fe1795a-5064-43d7-9a62-48b0f156a2c3",
        "C_ID": "1",
        "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c20b636c81d38dc77c627"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "ProductlistPage",
        "REFERER": "Home",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:45:25.064Z",
        "S_ID": "439667fe-ab24-4bf6-959e-152a4f631fe3",
        "C_ID": "595f40038c4d19b50ac21b98",
        "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c20f536c81d38dc77c628"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "ProductdetailsPage",
        "REFERER": "ProductlistPage",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:45:39.047Z",
        "S_ID": "a21c273a-372e-4a81-9997-d468d5efd299",
        "C_ID": "1",
        "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
        "P_ID": "595f3e418c4d19b50ac21b84",
        "P_NAME": "Martina",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c210236c81d38dc77c629"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "Home",
        "REFERER": "",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-28T05:47:15.604Z",
        "S_ID": "a4278659-8053-45fd-8a95-78766fd7541b",
        "C_ID": "",
        "C_NAME": "",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c216336c81d38dc77c62a"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "ProductlistPage",
        "REFERER": "Home",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-27T05:47:22.700Z",
        "S_ID": "874bb326-ab02-4061-a029-bef5977d4c65",
        "C_ID": "595f40038c4d19b50ac21b98",
        "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c216b36c81d38dc77c62b"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "CartPage",
        "REFERER": "ProductlistPage",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-27T05:47:25.758Z",
        "S_ID": "dd9096f9-79ea-4d86-81ce-149e364ab1ed",
        "C_ID": "1",
        "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c216d36c81d38dc77c62c"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "ProductdetailsPage",
        "REFERER": "ProductlistPage",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:47:42.047Z",
        "S_ID": "4ed84c84-80ec-4494-9ffe-453f19e2c079",
        "C_ID": "1",
        "P_ID": "595f3e418c4d19b50ac21b84",
        "P_NAME": "Martina",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c217d36c81d38dc77c62d"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "CartPage",
        "REFERER": "ProductdetailsPage",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:47:45.174Z",
        "S_ID": "91153a97-d79e-4d86-9872-5df51bd7e82f",
        "C_ID": "1",
        "P_ID": "595f3e418c4d19b50ac21b84",
        "P_NAME": "Martina",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c218136c81d38dc77c62e"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "59687ee6cd62a604e2bb0d1f",
        "PATH": "CustomershippingPage",
        "REFERER": "cartPage",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:48:20.386Z",
        "S_ID": "46866f41-9f43-4d28-a602-490db68dc029",
        "C_ID": "",
        "C_NAME": "",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "597c21a336c81d38dc77c62f",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c21a436c81d38dc77c630"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "59687ee6cd62a604e2bb0d1f",
        "PATH": "customerpayment",
        "REFERER": "CustomershippingPage",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-01-08T05:48:46.356Z",
        "S_ID": "56ad3bd7-854b-42e9-8443-46c514eb2ece",
        "C_ID": "",
        "C_NAME": "",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "597c21a336c81d38dc77c62f",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c21be36c81d38dc77c631"
       }
    ]
```

I need compare two arrays.find matches values and also count.

Example `arr` is a list of date.Compare the another array `arr1` based on `DATE_TIME`

`08-01-2017` is repeated one time. and `07-29-2017`  is repeated five times.

I need this output

```
 08-01-2017 - 2 <- Count(How many times repeated)
 07-29-2017 - 5
 07-28-2017 - 3 etc..
```

Each(arr) values are how many times repeated.

I have no idea.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: what output do you expected? this? [{d: 08-01-2017, c: 2}, [{d: 01-01-2010, c: 0}, ...]

Comment: The date formats in your array are not the same. 8-1-2017 doesn't occur in arr1 if you parse all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract out the date from your ISO date and then User array#reduce and array#filter to count the number of occurrences.

```js
const arr=["08-01-2017","07-31-2017","07-30-2017","07-29-2017","07-28-2017","07-27-2017","07-26-2017"];
const arr1= [
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "Home",
        "REFERER": "",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-31T05:44:06.743Z",
        "S_ID": "80067826-0cad-4806-b40e-8e5d8be18e53",
        "C_ID": "",
        "C_NAME": "",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c20a636c81d38dc77c626"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "ProductlistPage",
        "REFERER": "Home",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-30T05:44:22.425Z",
        "S_ID": "7fe1795a-5064-43d7-9a62-48b0f156a2c3",
        "C_ID": "1",
        "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c20b636c81d38dc77c627"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "ProductlistPage",
        "REFERER": "Home",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:45:25.064Z",
        "S_ID": "439667fe-ab24-4bf6-959e-152a4f631fe3",
        "C_ID": "595f40038c4d19b50ac21b98",
        "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c20f536c81d38dc77c628"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "ProductdetailsPage",
        "REFERER": "ProductlistPage",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:45:39.047Z",
        "S_ID": "a21c273a-372e-4a81-9997-d468d5efd299",
        "C_ID": "1",
        "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
        "P_ID": "595f3e418c4d19b50ac21b84",
        "P_NAME": "Martina",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c210236c81d38dc77c629"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "Home",
        "REFERER": "",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-28T05:47:15.604Z",
        "S_ID": "a4278659-8053-45fd-8a95-78766fd7541b",
        "C_ID": "",
        "C_NAME": "",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c216336c81d38dc77c62a"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "ProductlistPage",
        "REFERER": "Home",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-27T05:47:22.700Z",
        "S_ID": "874bb326-ab02-4061-a029-bef5977d4c65",
        "C_ID": "595f40038c4d19b50ac21b98",
        "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c216b36c81d38dc77c62b"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "CartPage",
        "REFERER": "ProductlistPage",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-27T05:47:25.758Z",
        "S_ID": "dd9096f9-79ea-4d86-81ce-149e364ab1ed",
        "C_ID": "1",
        "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c216d36c81d38dc77c62c"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "ProductdetailsPage",
        "REFERER": "ProductlistPage",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:47:42.047Z",
        "S_ID": "4ed84c84-80ec-4494-9ffe-453f19e2c079",
        "C_ID": "1",
        "P_ID": "595f3e418c4d19b50ac21b84",
        "P_NAME": "Martina",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c217d36c81d38dc77c62d"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "",
        "PATH": "CartPage",
        "REFERER": "ProductdetailsPage",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:47:45.174Z",
        "S_ID": "91153a97-d79e-4d86-9872-5df51bd7e82f",
        "C_ID": "1",
        "P_ID": "595f3e418c4d19b50ac21b84",
        "P_NAME": "Martina",
        "CART_ID": "",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c218136c81d38dc77c62e"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "59687ee6cd62a604e2bb0d1f",
        "PATH": "CustomershippingPage",
        "REFERER": "cartPage",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:48:20.386Z",
        "S_ID": "46866f41-9f43-4d28-a602-490db68dc029",
        "C_ID": "",
        "C_NAME": "",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "597c21a336c81d38dc77c62f",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c21a436c81d38dc77c630"
      },
      {
        "HOST": "",
        "U_ID": "59687ee6cd62a604e2bb0d1f",
        "PATH": "customerpayment",
        "REFERER": "CustomershippingPage",
        "AGENT": "",
        "OS": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "2017-01-08T05:48:46.356Z",
        "S_ID": "56ad3bd7-854b-42e9-8443-46c514eb2ece",
        "C_ID": "",
        "C_NAME": "",
        "P_ID": "",
        "P_NAME": "",
        "CART_ID": "597c21a336c81d38dc77c62f",
        "O_ID": "",
        "id": "597c21be36c81d38dc77c631"
       }
    ]

var result = arr.reduce((result, date) => {
  var occurances = arr1.filter((obj) => {
    let d = new Date(obj['DATE_TIME']);
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = d.getFullYear();

    if(day < 10){
        day='0'+day;
    } 
    if(month<10){
        month='0'+month;
    } 
    var newDate = month+'-'+day+'-'+year;
   
    return date === newDate;
  }).length;
  result[date] = occurances;
  return result;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it's a bit overcomplicated, isn't it?

Comment: @NinaScholz you write the most elegant code, yes, it's complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You could normalize your dates to an [ISO 6801](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string, as the timestamp of `DATE_TIME` is like. Then add just one in an object with dates as key.

```js
var data = [{ DATE_TIME: "2017-07-31T05:44:06.743Z" }, { DATE_TIME: "2017-07-30T05:44:22.425Z" }, { DATE_TIME: "2017-07-29T05:45:25.064Z" }, { DATE_TIME: "2017-07-29T05:45:39.047Z" }, { DATE_TIME: "2017-07-28T05:47:15.604Z" }, { DATE_TIME: "2017-07-27T05:47:22.700Z" }, { DATE_TIME: "2017-07-27T05:47:25.758Z" }, { DATE_TIME: "2017-07-29T05:47:42.047Z" }, { DATE_TIME: "2017-07-29T05:47:45.174Z" }, { DATE_TIME: "2017-07-29T05:48:20.386Z" }, { DATE_TIME: "2017-01-08T05:48:46.356Z" }],
    dates = ["08-01-2017", "07-31-2017", "07-30-2017", "07-29-2017", "07-28-2017", "07-27-2017", "07-26-2017"],
    count = Object.create(null);

dates.forEach(function (d) {
    count[d.replace(/(..)-(..)-(....)/, '$3-$1-$2')] = 0;
});
data.forEach(function (o) {
    var key = o.DATE_TIME.slice(0, 10);
    (key in count) && count[key]++;
});
   
console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can initially iterate over `arr` and put all its dates in result as keys with value 0. then you can iterate over your `arr1` and use each date as a key for result object and keep incrementing count for each date.
something like this:

```js
var arr=[
"08-01-2017",
"07-31-2017",
"07-30-2017",
"07-29-2017",
"07-28-2017",
"07-27-2017",
"07-26-2017"];

var arr1= [
  {
    "HOST": "",
    "U_ID": "",
    "PATH": "Home",
    "REFERER": "",
    "AGENT": "",
    "OS": "",
    "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-31T05:44:06.743Z",
    "S_ID": "80067826-0cad-4806-b40e-8e5d8be18e53",
    "C_ID": "",
    "C_NAME": "",
    "P_ID": "",
    "P_NAME": "",
    "CART_ID": "",
    "O_ID": "",
    "id": "597c20a636c81d38dc77c626"
  },
  {
    "HOST": "",
    "U_ID": "",
    "PATH": "ProductlistPage",
    "REFERER": "Home",
    "AGENT": "",
    "OS": "",
    "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-30T05:44:22.425Z",
    "S_ID": "7fe1795a-5064-43d7-9a62-48b0f156a2c3",
    "C_ID": "1",
    "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
    "P_ID": "",
    "P_NAME": "",
    "CART_ID": "",
    "O_ID": "",
    "id": "597c20b636c81d38dc77c627"
  },
  {
    "HOST": "",
    "U_ID": "",
    "PATH": "ProductlistPage",
    "REFERER": "Home",
    "AGENT": "",
    "OS": "",
    "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:45:25.064Z",
    "S_ID": "439667fe-ab24-4bf6-959e-152a4f631fe3",
    "C_ID": "595f40038c4d19b50ac21b98",
    "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
    "P_ID": "",
    "P_NAME": "",
    "CART_ID": "",
    "O_ID": "",
    "id": "597c20f536c81d38dc77c628"
  },
  {
    "HOST": "",
    "U_ID": "",
    "PATH": "ProductdetailsPage",
    "REFERER": "ProductlistPage",
    "AGENT": "",
    "OS": "",
    "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:45:39.047Z",
    "S_ID": "a21c273a-372e-4a81-9997-d468d5efd299",
    "C_ID": "1",
    "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
    "P_ID": "595f3e418c4d19b50ac21b84",
    "P_NAME": "Martina",
    "CART_ID": "",
    "O_ID": "",
    "id": "597c210236c81d38dc77c629"
  },
  {
    "HOST": "",
    "U_ID": "",
    "PATH": "Home",
    "REFERER": "",
    "AGENT": "",
    "OS": "",
    "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-28T05:47:15.604Z",
    "S_ID": "a4278659-8053-45fd-8a95-78766fd7541b",
    "C_ID": "",
    "C_NAME": "",
    "P_ID": "",
    "P_NAME": "",
    "CART_ID": "",
    "O_ID": "",
    "id": "597c216336c81d38dc77c62a"
  },
  {
    "HOST": "",
    "U_ID": "",
    "PATH": "ProductlistPage",
    "REFERER": "Home",
    "AGENT": "",
    "OS": "",
    "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-27T05:47:22.700Z",
    "S_ID": "874bb326-ab02-4061-a029-bef5977d4c65",
    "C_ID": "595f40038c4d19b50ac21b98",
    "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
    "P_ID": "",
    "P_NAME": "",
    "CART_ID": "",
    "O_ID": "",
    "id": "597c216b36c81d38dc77c62b"
  },
  {
    "HOST": "",
    "U_ID": "",
    "PATH": "CartPage",
    "REFERER": "ProductlistPage",
    "AGENT": "",
    "OS": "",
    "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-27T05:47:25.758Z",
    "S_ID": "dd9096f9-79ea-4d86-81ce-149e364ab1ed",
    "C_ID": "1",
    "C_NAME": "Sparklers",
    "P_ID": "",
    "P_NAME": "",
    "CART_ID": "",
    "O_ID": "",
    "id": "597c216d36c81d38dc77c62c"
  },
  {
    "HOST": "",
    "U_ID": "",
    "PATH": "ProductdetailsPage",
    "REFERER": "ProductlistPage",
    "AGENT": "",
    "OS": "",
    "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:47:42.047Z",
    "S_ID": "4ed84c84-80ec-4494-9ffe-453f19e2c079",
    "C_ID": "1",
    "P_ID": "595f3e418c4d19b50ac21b84",
    "P_NAME": "Martina",
    "CART_ID": "",
    "O_ID": "",
    "id": "597c217d36c81d38dc77c62d"
  },
  {
    "HOST": "",
    "U_ID": "",
    "PATH": "CartPage",
    "REFERER": "ProductdetailsPage",
    "AGENT": "",
    "OS": "",
    "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:47:45.174Z",
    "S_ID": "91153a97-d79e-4d86-9872-5df51bd7e82f",
    "C_ID": "1",
    "P_ID": "595f3e418c4d19b50ac21b84",
    "P_NAME": "Martina",
    "CART_ID": "",
    "O_ID": "",
    "id": "597c218136c81d38dc77c62e"
  },
  {
    "HOST": "",
    "U_ID": "59687ee6cd62a604e2bb0d1f",
    "PATH": "CustomershippingPage",
    "REFERER": "cartPage",
    "AGENT": "",
    "OS": "",
    "DATE_TIME": "2017-07-29T05:48:20.386Z",
    "S_ID": "46866f41-9f43-4d28-a602-490db68dc029",
    "C_ID": "",
    "C_NAME": "",
    "P_ID": "",
    "P_NAME": "",
    "CART_ID": "597c21a336c81d38dc77c62f",
    "O_ID": "",
    "id": "597c21a436c81d38dc77c630"
  },
  {
    "HOST": "",
    "U_ID": "59687ee6cd62a604e2bb0d1f",
    "PATH": "customerpayment",
    "REFERER": "CustomershippingPage",
    "AGENT": "",
    "OS": "",
    "DATE_TIME": "2017-01-08T05:48:46.356Z",
    "S_ID": "56ad3bd7-854b-42e9-8443-46c514eb2ece",
    "C_ID": "",
    "C_NAME": "",
    "P_ID": "",
    "P_NAME": "",
    "CART_ID": "597c21a336c81d38dc77c62f",
    "O_ID": "",
    "id": "597c21be36c81d38dc77c631"
   }
];

var result = {};


arr.forEach(function(date){
   result[date] = 0;
})


arr1.forEach(function(ob){
    var date = new Date(ob['DATE_TIME']);
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    m = m > 9 ? m : '0' + m;
    var d = date.getDate() + 1;
    d = d > 9 ? d : '0' + d;
    date = m + '-' + d + '-' +  date.getFullYear();
    result[date] = date in result ? parseInt(result[date]) + 1 : 1;
})


console.log(result);
```

Comment: Where exactly are you comparing arr1 with arr? I think you miss understood his question

Comment: @masterfan it was more likely to be an idea, check now, i have update code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems safe to assume that date parts have a fixed number of characters. Therefore:

```
arr1.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const key = item.DATE_TIME.substr(0,10);
  if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) { acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + 1 }
  return acc;
}, {})
```